# Django display a variable in another template

Tags: python, django

I have a django project, where I have two templates: notification.html and base.html. Using get_context_data() method I display the number of answers at the notification.html. I tried to use the same variable in base.html, but it didn't work. I also created CBV that and used get_context_data() to pass the same logic and display it at the base.html, but it doesn't work. How do I display the variable in another template?

I don't how to pass 'answers.count' to the base.html, if base.html doesn't have a view (I created this only now trying to display this variable).

forum.views

```
class NotificationView(ListView):
model = Answer
template_name = 'forum/notification.html'

# If user visited the notification page - mark all answers as read
def get_queryset(self):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    question = Question.objects.filter(user=user)
    answer_read = self.model.objects.filter(question__in=question)
    answer_read.update(is_read=True)
    return answer_read

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    question = Question.objects.filter(user=user)
    context['answers_all'] = Answer.objects.filter(question__in=question).order_by('-date_posted')
    context['answers'] = Answer.objects.filter(question__in=question, is_read=False)
    return context
```

forum/notification.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <b>УNotofocations: {{ answers.count }}</b>
        {% for answer in answers_all %}
        <div class="card mb-3 mt-2">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="{% url 'detail' answer.question.id %}" class="mb-2">Ответ на вопрос: {{ answer.question }}</a>
                <p>{{ answer.detail }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'users_questions' answer.user.username %}">{{ answer.user.username }}</a>
                <span class="ml-4">{{ answer.date_posted|naturalday }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

main.views

```
class BaseView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'main/base.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    question = Question.objects.filter(user=user)
    context['answers'] = Answer.objects.filter(question__in=question)
    return context
```

main/base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if answers.count < 1 %}
        <a href="{% url 'notification' user.username %}" class="bell text-light mr-3" id="btn-bell"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'notification' user.username %}" class="bell text-light mr-3" id="btn-bell"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i><span class="pending">{{ answers.count }}</span></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: where is base.html extend in your notification.html ?

Comment: I have this extend. I just forgot to copy it. I think that the problem is that I can’t pass “answers.count” through the context data to base.html.

Answer (score 1):

guess you are only missing the build-in template tags

in forum/notification.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

in main/base.html

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#extends

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Comment: I have it. I just didn’t copy that. I guess that the problem is that I don’t understand how to pass context data to the base.html if there is no View that renders this page

Comment: if view renders notification and notification extends base - you render base with notification together

Comment: At notification page everything works fine, it also extends the base.html. Context data variable shows the number of answers. I also tried to pass this variable at base.html , but nothing displays. I think that I need to define this variable again in view, that renders base.html, but I don't have such a View. So the questions was how do I display one variable at both pages: at notification.html and base.html. I'll change the code to show you more details.

Comment: @Maxim Danilov, also I tried `{% include 'forum/notification.html' with answers=answers %}`, but it shows mistakes as well.

Comment: Can you provide base.html too?

Comment: @MaximDanilov, yes, I've changed the code in description

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem. The idea was to display the variable from context_data at base.html. As `get_context_data` didn't help, I found the solution in Django documentation. The solution was so easy, I hope to save time for other learners if they got the same problem.

I used `context_processors.py` to pass extra information and display it on the page. My step were:

1. Created a `context_processors.py` file in my app directory.
2. Created a function `def get_notifications_number(request)` where I filter what I want to display at base.html and returned `return {'answers': answers}`
3. Finally, I registered the file in Django TEMPLATES `'my_app.context_processors.get_notifications_number'`.